# GAE: know when data is put in Memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I want to know when data is put on Memcache ... Why ?

I have data in memcache with an expiration time of 30 minutes.

I want to update this data when someone ask after 5 minutes to the storage time.

Should I have to put 2 data like key=>data and key_time=>date or it's possible to know when data was store ?

I'm using Java.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Sorry :/
I want to know when a data was stored on memcache. I just have the key of this data.

Answer (score 1):

Key_time option can be hard to manage later. How will you find your key?

Its better to store it in a dictionary, i.e:

```
Key => {'time': time.time(), 'data': your_data}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when the data was written to memcache, simply store that information along with your data. For instance, instead of storing the value `"foo"` under the key `"bar"`, store the tuple `("foo", current_timestamp)`, where `current_timestamp` is the time at which you're making the put request.